# fgetcsv not reading columns which has special characters in PHP

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, fgetcsv

I am unable to get the column value which contains some special characters. I have checked many answers but i got no idea. I have pasted my sample code and data here,

```
$pHandle = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($pHandle, 1600, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo $productName =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($data[0])));exit;
 }
```

It echo's nothing.

some sample data's

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the CSV data well-formed?  For example, does any string that contains a comma have quote marks around it?

Comment: @GordonM updated an image. The column has `-(),` even it has **single quote**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function fgetcsv is not reading the string because the string contains an unknown character `"-"(shown in the image) it's not hypen`, i replaced the character by `"-"hyphen` and it worked.

[image]